# Jquery variablie with value 0 strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, variables, alert

I have such code

```
if(itemid){
   expandHighlight(itemid);
}


function expandHighlight(itemid){
    alert(itemid);
}
```

Sure, it works as it should, but if itemid has value of "0" (int) - nothing happening. A get no alert, just nothig... any ideas?

Comment: `0 == false` in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make your `if` more sensible:

```
if(itemid !== undefined)
```

Or remove it entirely

Comment: +1, just changed it to the more stable way of checking `undefined`, since the other way can be compromised by just having `var undefined = true;` etc etc

Comment: You can't change `undefined`. I have no idea what you're talking about, I rolled back that edit.

Comment: (besides everything but the string `'undefined'` is `!== 'undefined'`)

Comment: `typeof ('undefined') !== 'undefined'` would work, `'undefined'` is a string

Comment: Not to mention this will throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: itemid is not defined ` if the var isn't even defined.

Comment: I don't see the point in guarding against not even declaring a variable, and replacing `undefined`. I _would want_ those kinds of things to **break** my code.

Answer (score 4):

It is because `if ("0")` is falsy and it wouldn't call the `expandHighlight` function.